# Jmeter inconsistent result across networks

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing

Both graphs show 300 threads, 30 ramp up time, 40 loops

Performed with home network:
Average response: 1445 millisecond

[image]

Performed with a different network (fast network, 250 Mbps speed for download and upload):
Average response: 90 milliseconds!
[image]

Why does the second network show no sign of error or heavy load? In fact, the average time is just 90 milliseconds and no thread took longer than 1 second. Is this due to network 2 being much faster or something else?
I even tried 1000 threads, 1 ramp up time for second network and avg response still below 1 second. The end point is not heavy work, no database access. How i'm i supposed to perform load and stress test when i am getting different results for different network?

Comment: This is normal. There are multiple variables involved for this difference such as network bandwidth, time of execution, system configuration etc. Each run in each environment yields different results. Higher bandwidth provides better response time. To simulate real world scenario, you need to perform the tests in varying network conditions and valid workload model. The objective of load and stress is different. In load testing, you need to study the behavior under defined workload say 50 users. In stress testing, you need to identify the breaking point by injecting 50+ users. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. Will the breaking point be similar or different between slow network and fast network? I assume they will be similar because it should be showing how much the server  can handle, right? The only difference is the loads that is put on from jmeter. fast network will need more load. im i right?

Comment: It depends. If the code is bad, it will fail in lower bandwidth and higher bandwidth. Your test must be optimum and the workload should simulate real world scenario. Run the load and stress test in a identical environment as production.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your load test results are not inline

- On upper image you have 250 maximum virtual users and 3 minutes test duration
- On lower image you have 100 maximum virtual users and 40 seconds test duration

So I don't think it was the same test, load pattern is totally different.

Make sure that:

1. You run the **same test** against 2 environments
2. You monitor baseline OS health metrics on the application under test side (CPU, RAM, Disk and if you suspect network hardware to be the bottleneck, Network IO). You can use [JMeter PerfMon Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-monitor-your-server-health-performance-during-jmeter-load-test) for this
3. You pay attention to the following JMeter metrics:

   - Connect Time
   - Latency
   - Throughput

     See [JMeter Glossary](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/glossary.html) for detailed explanation of their meaning.

Comment: Thanks, how do i keep a constant increasing rate of 10 threads every second for 1 hour? 300 threads, 30 ramp up time will only do 10 threads per second for 30 seconds. Thank you